# Smoothing / noise filtering data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, smoothing

I have table with data as follows

```
article price   wished outcome
horse    10         10
duck     15         15
child    9        15 - 21
panda    21         21
lamb     24         22
gorilla  23         23
```

I want to smooth column Price to the wished Price and then put it into dataframe, so that I see the values.

[image: Desired output]

Please, is there some built in library - method that smoothens the data?
in this format?

I found savitzky-golay filter, moving average, etc.
But I fail to make it on these kind of data - where x axis is some product = not value.

Please, can you help?

Thanks!!!

```
 d = {'Price': [10, 15, 9, 21,24,23], 'Animal': ['horse', 'lamb', 'gorilla', 'child','panda','duck']}
 df = pd.DataFrame(d)

 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
 from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
 from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
 import numpy as np

 x = np.arange(1,len(df)+1)
 y = df['Price']

 xx = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(), 1001)

 # interpolate + smooth
 itp = interp1d(x,y, kind='quadratic') #kind = 'linear', 'nearest' (dobre      vysledky), slinear (taky ok), cubic (nebrat), quadratic - nebrat
 window_size, poly_order = 1001, 1
 yy_sg = savgol_filter(itp(xx), window_size, poly_order)


 # or fit to a global function
 # to stejne jako scipy.optimize.curve.fit 
 def func(x, A, B, x0, sigma):
     return A+B*np.tanh((x-x0)/sigma)

 fit, _ = curve_fit(func, x, y)
 yy_fit = func(xx, *fit)

 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))
 ax.plot(x, y, 'r.', label= 'Unsmoothed curve')
 ax.plot(xx, yy_fit, 'b--', label=r"$f(x) = A + B \tanh\left(\frac{x-x_0}     {\sigma}\right)$")
 ax.plot(xx, yy_sg, 'k', label= "Smoothed curve")
 plt.legend(loc='best')


 I am getting : AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'min'
```

Savitzky golay is producing very strange values.
With window lenght 1000

[image]

When I set window to len(df) +1 (in order it to be odd) then I get these data:

[image]

Comment: Can you try the same again by using `x = range(1, len(xdata))`?

Comment: Please, see my edits of code that I am using - I am getting error

Comment: Can you add the code that creates the object `df`?

Comment: Replace `xx = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(), 1001)` by `xx = np.linspace(min(x),max(x), 1001)`

Comment: Ok, first replace `x = range(1,len(df))` by `x = range(1,len(df)+1)` to have equal lengths of `x` and `y`. Also, `window_size, poly_order = 1001, 1` will give you a linear interpolation. Try `poly_order` as 2, 3, 4 to see the output

Comment: Try `kind='linear'` and `poly_order` as `3`

Comment: The thing is when I make window 1000 then 1000 values are made. I need the exact 1 value for each animal. But when I set window to len(df) then I dont get good values, since the line only connects the points..

Comment: I found it = I have to change xx = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(), 1001)  to xx = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(), len(df) + 1) . Also window_size, poly_order = len(df) + 1 , 1

Comment: Try adding these two lines to your code `fit1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 3))`
 and `ax.plot(x, fit1(x), '-ko', label= "Smoothed curve")`. Here I am using a third degree polynomial fit and then passing *actual* `x` data points from your DataFrame to plot *only* the corresponding 1 value for each animal.

Comment: Thanks. BY any chance, dont you know about any other method how I can smooth data? another filter? method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178460/discussion-between-bazingaa-and-headoverfeet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because of the following line:
`x = range(1,len(df))`.

As the error tells you, a `range` object has no attribute `min`.

However, `numpy.array()`s do, so if you change that line to 
`x = np.arange(1, len(df))` then this error (at least) will disappear.

EDIT:
In order for the function to do what you want it to do, you should change it to `x = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)`

Comment: Edit your answer: `a range object has attribute min` with `a range object has no attribute min`. You are missing the main point "NO" here

Comment: Read my above comments for `range(1, len(df)+1)`. Plz edit your answer